# Is there any event handler that can detect the change in System date, in java?

Tags: java

Change in date both manually and automatically (i.e when clock hits 12 AM) should be detected. I don't want to use any kind of scheduler that delays the tasks in certain interval because my program may not always remain opened at 12 AM. And I want to avoid, as much as possible, the thought of running a constant check of time in background (using thread runnable).

Comment: if your program is not always running, you cant detect date change with dead process. you can use system scheduler to run your task.

Comment: Can you explain what system scheduler is and what it does?

Comment: @pratik.gamer windows - http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/schedule-task  nix - http://www.howtogeek.com/101288/how-to-schedule-tasks-on-linux-an-introduction-to-crontab-files/

Comment: @MohammadAdil Is that even Java programming?

Comment: @pratik.gamer if your program is not running, what do you think, is it possible with java ?

Comment: Oh sorry for not explaining properly. You might have misunderstood that I want to run a certain code when my program is not running. What I actually mean is my program may not always run but at least when it is running, I want it to detect a change in System date.